# Confidence Interval for Mu in a Log normal Distributions in R

Tags: r, distribution, confidence-interval, mu

Suppose we have a random sample of size n = 8 from a lognormal distribution with parameters mu and sigma.  Since it is a small sample, from a non-normal population I will be using the t confidence interval.  I ran a simulation to determine the true (simulated) CI of a 90% t-CI in which mu=1 and sigma= 1.5

My problem is that my code below follows a NORMAL distribution and it needs to be a lognormal distribution. 
I know that rnorm has to become rlnorm so that the random variables come from the log distribution. But I need to change what mu and sigma are. Mu and sigma in normal distribution aren't the same in a log distribution.

Mu in the log distribution= exp(μ + 1/2 σ^2).  And sigma is  exp (2 (μ+sigma^2)) – exp2 (μ+sigma^2)

I'm just confused on how I can incorporate these two equations into my code.

BTW- if you didn't already guess, I am VERY new to R. Any help would be appreciated!

---

```
MC <- 10000 # Number of samples to simulate
result <- c(1:MC)
mu <- 1
sigma <- 1.5
n <- 8; # Sample size
alpha <- 0.1 # the nominal confidence level is 100(1-alpha) percent

    t_criticalValue <- qt(p=(1-alpha/2), df=(n-1))

    for(i in 1:MC){
    mySample <- rlnorm(n=n, mean=mu, sd=sigma)
    lowerCL <- mean(mySample)-t_criticalValue*sd(mySample)/sqrt(n)
    upperCL <- mean(mySample)+t_criticalValue*sd(mySample)/sqrt(n)
    result[i] <- ((lowerCL < mu) & (mu < upperCL))
    }

SimulatedConfidenceLevel <- mean(result)
```

EDIT: So I tried  replacing mu and sd with their respective formulas...

(mu=exp(μ + 1/2 σ2)
Sigma= exp(2μ + σ2)(exp(σ2) - 1)

and I got a simulatedconfidencelevel of 5000.

Comment: Please can you clarify what you are trying to calculate: distributions don't have confidence intervals.  Are you trying to calculate a confidence interval for `mu`?  Or are you trying to determine if your data came from a lognormal distribution with `mu = 1` and `sigma = 1.5`?  Or something else?

Comment: yes, I'm trying to calculate the "true" or stimulated confidence interval for mu/mean

Answer (score 0):

Here's some reproducible sample data:

```
(x <- rlnorm(8, 1, 1.5))
## [1]  3.5415832  0.3563604  0.5052436  3.5703968  7.3696985  0.7737094 12.9768734 35.9143985
```

Your definition of the critical value was correct:

```
n <- length(x)
alpha <- 0.1 
t_critical_value <- qt(1 - alpha / 2, n - 1)
```

There's a utility function in the `ggplot2` plotting package that calculates means and standard errors.  In this case, you can apply it to the log of your data to find `mu` and it's confidence interval.

```
library(ggplot2)
mean_se(log(x), t_critical_value)    
##          y         ymin     ymax
## 1 1.088481 -0.006944755 2.183907
```